# text-align: right not working for th element

Tags: html, css

Why I can't I right align the text in the th?

https://jsfiddle.net/btzatLb7/1/

**HTML:**

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Averages:</th>
    <tr>
    <tr class="average_labels">
      <td id="minute_label">1 min</td>
      <td id="minute_label">5 min</td>
      <td id="minute_label">15 min</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="average_data">
      <td id="one_minute">2.30</td>
      <td id="five_minute">2.24</td>
      <td id="fifteen_minute">2.01</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**CSS:**
*EVEN USING !important !*

```
th {text-align: right!important;}
```

Comment: Try doing `<th colspan="3">` - Your table has three columns, as indicated by your three `<td>` elements. Your `<th>` is only one column wide, so it will right-align *to that column*. If you want the one `<th>` to span across three columns, you need `colspan="3"`.

Comment: your th is for 1 column, this style works but since you have only 1 column its effect is not easy to view

Comment: Add this rule to your CSS and you can easily see the issue: `table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `<th colspan="3">` instead of `<th>`.

---

**What's wrong with your current code:**

Your table has three columns, as indicated by your three `<td>` elements. Your `<th>` is only one column wide, so it will right-align *to that column*. Take a look at this demonstration below:

```css
th {text-align: right;}
 
th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Averages:</th>
    <tr>
      <tr class="average_labels">
        <td id="minute_label">1 min</td>
        <td id="minute_label">5 min</td>
        <td id="minute_label">15 min</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="average_data">
        <td id="one_minute">2.30</td>
        <td id="five_minute">2.24</td>
        <td id="fifteen_minute">2.01</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

---

**How to fix it:**

If you want the single `<th>` to span across three columns, you need to specify  `colspan="3"`.

```css
th {text-align: right;}
 
th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Averages:</th>
    <tr>
      <tr class="average_labels">
        <td id="minute_label">1 min</td>
        <td id="minute_label">5 min</td>
        <td id="minute_label">15 min</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="average_data">
        <td id="one_minute">2.30</td>
        <td id="five_minute">2.24</td>
        <td id="fifteen_minute">2.01</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```